# Tech-stack for querying and alerting on GB scale (streaming and at rest) datasets

Tags: database, postgresql, elasticsearch, statistics, bigdata

Trying to scope out a project that involves data ingestion and analytics, and could use some advice on tooling and software.

We have sensors creating records with 2-3 fields, each one producing ~200 records per second (~2kb/second) and will send them off to a remote server once per minute resulting in about ~18 mil records and 200MB of data per day per sensor. Not sure how many sensors we will need but it will likely start off in the single digits.

We need to be able to take action (alert) on recent data (not sure the time period guessing less than 1 day), as well as run queries on the past data. We'd like something that scales and is relatively stable .

Was thinking about using elastic search (then maybe use x-pack or sentinl for alerting). Thought about Postgres as well. Kafka and Hadoop are definitely overkill. We're on AWS so we have access to tools like kinesis as well.

Question is, what would be an appropriate set of software / architecture for the job?

Comment: I would consider Cassandra or Elasticsearch. Both can handle time series data efficiently; Elastic stack got nice visualization / data analytics tools while C* got its on advantages in terms of storage.

Answer (score 0):

Have you talked to your AWS Solutions Architect about the use case? They love this kind of thing, they'll be happy to help you figure out the right architecture. It may be a good fit for the [AWS IoT services](https://aws.amazon.com/iot/)?

If you don't go with the managed IoT services, you'll want to push the messages to a scalable queue like Kafka or Kinesis (IMO, if you are processing 18M * 5 sensors = 90M events per day, that's >1000 events per second. Kafka is not overkill here; a lot of other stacks would be *under-kill*).

From Kinesis you then flow the data into a faster stack for analytics / querying, such as HBase, Cassandra, Druid or ElasticSearch, depending on your team's preferences. Some would say that this is time series data so you should use a [time series database](https://db-engines.com/en/ranking/time+series+dbms) such as InfluxDB; but again, it's up to you. Just make sure it's a database that performs well (and behaves itself!) when subjected to a steady load of 1000 writes per second. I would not recommend using a RDBMS for that, not even Postgres. The ones mentioned above should all handle it.

Also, don't forget to flow your messages from Kinesis to S3 for safe keeping, even if you don't intend to keep the messages forever (just set a lifecycle rule to delete old data from the bucket if that's the case). After all, this is big data and the rule is "*everything breaks, all the time*". If your analytical stack crashes you probably don't want to lose the data entirely.

As for alerting, it depends 1) what stack you choose for the analytical part, and 2) what kinds of triggers you want to use. From your description I'm guessing you'll soon end up wanting to build more advanced triggers, such as machine learning models for anomaly detection, and for that you may want something that doesn't poll the analytical stack but rather consumes events straight out of Kinesis.